# Initialize a structure with an array in a variable

Tags: c

How can we initialize a structure with an array (using its variable)?

This version works well:

```
MyStruct test = {"hello", 2009};
```

But this version is bugged:

```
char str[] = "hello";
MyStruct test = {str, 2009};
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the definition of 'typedef struct MyStruct { ... } MyStruct;'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign arrays in C, so unfortunately there's no way to do that directly.  You may use strcpy to copy the data, though.

```
typedef struct {
  char name[20];
  int year;
} MyStruct;

int main() {
  MyStruct a = { "hello", 2009 }; // works

  char s[] = "hello";
  MyStruct b = { "", 2009 }; // use dummy value
  strcpy(b.name, s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would use strlcpy() or strncpy_s() if available.  strncpy() as a semi-last resort.  strcpy() only if you know that it won't overflow and feel like making god cry.

Comment: Good point. I recommended strcpy because it's standard, he's likely seen it already, and he's guaranteed to have it.

Comment: You can do array assignments as part of a structure assignment: `struct a { int b[10]; } a, b = { 0 };  a = b;`

Comment: @asveikau, better use snprintf() instead of strncpy(), this will ensure that your string is nul-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `MyStruct` should contain a first member of type `char const *`.

Comment: Or, slightly more expansively, if the definition of MyStruct contained a char pointer (or, better, a 'const char *'), then the second initializer would work correctly.